# возвратить дополнительную колонку с алгоритмом подсчета данных

Tags: sql, postgresql

Еще раз доброго дня!
ДАНО:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ЗАДАЧА:
Необходимо добавить 5-ую колонку "chage" в которой будут фиксироваться изменения в колонке
team в текущей игре относительно ее предыдущего матча.
Прошу помочь

ВИЗУАЛЬНЫЙ РЕЗУЛЬТАТ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.windowfunctions.com/?

Comment: спасибо изучаю. только там по моей задаче ничего нет

Comment: *там по моей задаче ничего нет* Плохо изучаете. `column - LEAD(column)`

Comment: Спасибо Айнар. Спасибо Акина. Решение найдено, добавил его в "Вопрос"

Comment: Только не получилось возвратить верный результат если сортировать по столбцу match_date. То есть если в конце кода написать ORDER BY match_date DESC, то результат не верен

Comment: Решение надо давать в ответы, а не в вопрос. Используйте кнопку "ответить на собственный вопрос"

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено:
SELECT
id,
match_date,
team,
score,
LEAD (team,0) OVER() - LAG (team) OVER () AS change
FROM matches
WHERE EXTRACT('year'FROM match_date) = 2017